# Нюанс с передачами массивов в функции

Tags: массивы, указатели, функции

Всем добрый день/вечер/утро, смотря у кого какое время. Я немного запутался с передачей массивов в функцию, и желаю услышать объективное мнение по поводу того, что я думаю.

Есть у меня такая функция (даже не важно, что в ней реализовано):

```
void readingCities(ifstream file, Queue *queue) {
    char *word = new char[STR_MAX];
    char *city = new char[MAX];
    unsigned int iCount, jCount, kCount = 0;

    for (iCount= 0; file.getline(word, STR_MAX); iCount++) {
        for (jCount = 0; jCount < strlen(word); jCount++) {
            city[jCount] = word[jCount];
            if (isspace(word[jCount])) {
                city[jCount] = '\0';
                if (!kCount) {
                    queue = (Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue));
                    queue[iCount].main = city;
                }
                else {
                    queue = (Queue*) realloc(queue, sizeof(Queue) * (kCount + 1));
                    queue[iCount].analogs[kCount - 1] = city;
                }
            }
            kCount++;
        }
        kCount = 0;
    }
}
```

И есть такой код:

```
int main()
{
    Queue *newQueue;
    ifstream fileOrigin;

    fileOrigin.open("1.txt");
    readingCities(fileOrigin, newQueue);
    fileOrigin.close();
    delete [] newQueue;
    return 0;
}
```

По идеи, нужно в самой функции сделать двойной указатель (то есть Queue **queue вместо Queue* queue), а когда ее вызываешь, нужно ставить &newQueue вместо newQueue, тогда скорее всего будет работать.

Так вот, вопрос, можно ли сделать так, чтобы избежать использования двойного указателя? Ведь по сути, я намудрил тут такого, а если еще и везде в функции вместо queue ставить (*queue) то вообще будет каша.

Спасибо заранее.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать reference:

```
void readingCities(ifstream file, Queue *&queue)
```

и вызывать как сейчас:

```
readingCities(fileOrigin, newQueue);
```

Comment: @beraliv: в функции `queue` — это указатель (тот же, что и внешний `queue`), сама очередь — `*queue`. Компилятор не даст вам сделать неправильно.

Comment: Скажите, а вот у меня была newQueue, которую я указываю при вызове функции, она перед этим должна быть инициализированна? У меня куча ошибок, вообще не могу разобраться в коде?

Comment: @beraliv: Ну, в вашем случае не надо, потому что она инициализируется строкой `queue = (Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue))`. Но я бы всё же писал в стиле C++, и отказался от `char*` в пользу `std::string`, и от явного выделения и перевыделения памяти для `queue` в пользу использования стандартного контейнера (скорее всего, вам нужен просто `std::vector<>`). В этом случае вероятность ошибиться существенно меньше.

Comment: Тогда я не понимаю, почему ошибки. У меня такого рода ошибки:


'std::ios_base::ios_base(const std::ios_base&)' is private
c:\qtsdk\mingw\bin\..\lib\gcc\mingw32\4.4.0\include\c++\streambuf:770


'std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>::basic_streambuf(const std::basic_streambuf<_CharT, _Traits>&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>]' is private

Comment: А на что ругается?

---
Кстати, вы не должны удалять `newQueue` посредством `delete/delete[]`: если выделяете через `malloc`, удаляйте через `free`! Но всё же лучше переделать на стандартные контейнеры.

Comment: Ругается на какие-то вещи, которые находятся в iostream библиотеке, а вообще delete[] тут роли пока не играет, он на него внимание не обращает


А в принципе я вот закомментил код в функции

Оставил обращение к функции и функцию, так вот ему не нравится обращение к функции:

    void readingCities(ifstream file, Queue *&queue) {...}
    Queue *newQueue;
    ofstream fileOutput;                        // file with the result
    ifstream fileOrigin, fileInput;             // reading files

    fileOrigin.open("1.txt");
    readingCities(fileOrigin, newQueue);       // вот этот вызов ему не нра

Comment: @beraliv: понятно, почему. Вы передаёте `file` по значению, то есть фактически копию. А скопировать его невозможно (нет конструктора копирования), да и неправильно. Передавайте и `file` то ссылке:

    void readingCities(ifstream& file, Queue *&queue)

Comment: и тут вы правы :) вы мне так помогли, я прямо Вам благодарен всей душой, спасибо огромное!

Comment: @beraliv: пожалуйста! C++ — непростой язык, удачи вам в его изучении!

Comment: @beraliv, передача по ссылке весьма запутывает понимание программы. Обычно чужой (а через полгода, год и своей тоже).

Читая код, и не глядя на каждый прототип, люди обычно считают, что вызов вида:

   f(a);

никогда не меняет **`a`**, а вот:

  f(&a);

обычно меняет.

--

В данном же случае, программируя в стиле Си, логично было бы написать так

   Queue *readingCities(FILE *file) {
      Queue *queue = 0;
      ...
      return queue;
   } 

поскольку Вы там всегда создаете `queue`.

Ну, а если надо менять уже существую, то

   Queue *readingCities(FILE *file, Queue *queue); // прототип